# QGIS aggregate expression to filter selected features in 2nd layer

Tags: qgis, relates, plot, aggregate, qgsexpression

I´m working with two layers in QGIS:

1. First one with point geometries representing water quality sampling places (LAYER A).
2. The second is a spreadsheet (no geometries) that contains pollution values at different times (LAYER B).

Both layers linked with a relate (one to many) based on the station ID. Relate works as the LAYER B data are preented in the info form when clicking LAYER A features.

The aim is to get time series graphs using Data Plotly plugin, but apparently it is not designed to work with relates.

I´ve come to the conclussion that the only way to get the plots is to set LAYER B in the plugin and then limit the feature subset to the records that match the STATION_ID of the selected feature in LAYER A. I´ve tried this with an expression of the sort

```
STATION_ID = 
aggregate(layer,aggregate,expression
[,filter][,concatenator])
```

where layer is LAYER A,
aggregate is 'concatenate',
and expression would be the field contaning the STATION_ID

but cannot guess what the expression of the filter should be so that only the data of the selected feature is presented in the plot. Also i´m aware that in case that more than one features are selected, the concatenate wouldn`t work.

Any idea how to solve this? Another way to get the selected STATION_ID from LAYER A?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but here is how you can get selected features of another layer using `aggregate()` expression as asked in your question's title:

```
aggregate('LayerB','array_agg',"id",is_selected('LayerB',$currentfeature))
```

Of course you can also use other stuff than `'array_agg'` and other fields/features/geometries than `"id"`. Also you could get the not selected features, by simply using `not` in front of `is_selected()`:

```
aggregate('LayerB','array_agg',"id",not is_selected('LayerB',$currentfeature))
```

The trick is to **pass two arguments** to the `is_selected()` function in the filter argument of `aggregate()`: the `layername` **and** the `feature`.

> If the function is called with both a layer and a feature, it will
> return true if the specified feature from the specified layer is
> selected.

Comment: Yesss! Thank you MrXquared, that worked. Although I had problems with array_agg and change to concatenate instead. I suppose because STATION_ID contains only one value, and dont´t match an array type. But I have to try again and see.